# is html helper possible for below case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Currently, I am using below code for one of MVC 3 app, where,

1. depend upon which particular menu item is clicked, I need to change the "LI" style ("menu-active" and "menu-inactive").
2. each menu item contains within div has different class (for example HOME menu has "divClassHome" style, other has other respectively).

Is any html helper possible here as I have 20+ menu items, hence code is copy paste for each set, please suggest!

```
if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString() ==    "Home" && ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "Index")
{
<li class="menu-active">
<div class="DivClassHome">
  @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "XYZ" })
</div>
```

}
        else
        {
         
          
          @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "XYZ" })
          
          
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/V2#navs). It takes care of selecting the active menu items with extension method `.SetLinksActiveByControllerAndAction()`:

```
using (var nav = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Nav().SetLinksActiveByControllerAndAction()))
{
    @nav.ActionLink("Link 1", "action1")
    @nav.ActionLink("Link 2", "action2")
    @nav.Link("External Link", "#")
}
```